# Странное поведение Case в Ruby

Tags: ruby, case

Делаю фильтр, который выбирает данные из файла yaml. Сам yaml передается в переменную @result. @requests - это набор ответов пользователей, которые сохраняются в хеш.
В консоли это выглядит примерно так:

Введите первый запрос:
item1
Введите второй запрос:
item2

Результат:
item1
item2
и другие данные из yaml по запросам.

**Проблема:** когда заполняю все данные, которые запрашиваются в консоли, результат выводиться. Когда ввожу только item1, а item2 пропускаю (или наоборот), результат по одному из запросов выводиться уже не хочет. Специально ввожу правильные ключевые запросы, которые совпадают в базе.

**Я пробовала** прописывать условия по типу "Если item1 заполнен, а item2 пустой, то выводи все результаты по item1 (и наоборот)". Но это не помогает. Возможно кто-то сможет предположить, в чем проблема?

```
  @requests.each do |key, value|
   @result =    case key
                when 'item1'
                 @result.select{ |key| key['item1'] == value }
                when 'item2'
                @result.select{ |key| key['item2'] == value }
                else
                @result
                end
end
```

**Дополнение:**
Пример файла yaml, который передается в @result:

```
- id: 1457848
  manufacturer: Airbus 
  model: A220
  year: 2003
  price: 120000
  date_added: 18/09/21
- id: 1457849
  manufacturer: Airbus
  model: A318
  year: 1999
  price: 190000
  date_added: 15/07/21
- id: 1457849
  manufacturer: Airbus
  model: A318
  year: 2005
  price: 195000
  date_added: 15/07/21
- id: 145784910
  manufacturer: Boeing
  model: A757
  year: 2008
  price: 1370000
  date_added: 10/08/21
- id: 145784911
  manufacturer: Comac
  model: C919
  year: 2019
  price: 3400000
  date_added: 12/01/21
- id: 145784911
  manufacturer: Boeing
  model: 737 MAX
  year: 2015
  price: 8750000
  date_added: 19/08/21
```

Передается в @result следующим образом через initialize в файле класса Search:

```
  def initialize requests
   @result = YAML::load(File.open('airplanes.yaml'))
   @requests = requests
  end
```

Файл @requests:

```
class Requests
  
 def self.requests
  
  puts "Enter manufacturer: "
  entered_manufacturer = gets.strip
  
  puts "Enter the model: "
  entered_model = gets.strip
  
  save = { 'manufacturer' => entered_manufacturer, 'model' => entered_model }
  
  end
    
end
```

Эти сохраненные requests передаются через новый объект класса Search в файле index-airplanes.rb:

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'requests.rb'
require_relative 'search_airplanes.rb'

requests = Requests.requests
search = Search.new requests

puts search.results
```

Файл класса Search (в нем лежит основной метод самого поиска:

```
class Search
 
  def initialize requests
   @result = YAML::load(File.open('airplanes.yaml'))
   @requests = requests
  end
  
  def results
  
   def case_result_function
   
    @requests.each do |key, value|

      @result = case key
                when 'manufacturer'
                 @result.select{ |item| item['manufacturer'] == value }
                when 'model'
                 @result.select{ |item| item['model'] == value }
                else
                 @result
                end
     end  
  @result
   end
   
  case_result_function
  end               
end
```

Comment: В вопросе не хватает примеров `@requests` и `@result`, чтобы понять, что тут происходит и как оно работает, если `@result` каждый раз перезаписывается

Comment: Обновила информацию по файлам, разместила после слова "Дополнение".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь стало понятнее, что у вас тут происходит. Проблема в том, что если ничего не ввести, то под одним из ключей сохранится пустая строка, например `{"manufacturer"=>"Airbus", "model"=>""}`, а значит `select` вернёт вам пустой хэш (ведь у ваc нет таких записей, где значение было бы пустым). Значит наша задача - вернуть весь `@result` в таком случае. Ну и case statement тут в общем-то лишний.

```
@requests.each do |key, value|
  next if value.blank?

  @result = @result.select{ |item| item[key] == value }
end
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, все работает.